# ASP.NET MVC3 vs Silverlight4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, silverlight-4.0

Why these two tecnologies? Which are the key decisions choosing one of them? Guidelines and scenarios?

ASP.NET MVC3 provides several capabilities that Silverlight4 does not: ...

Silverlight4 provides several capabilities that ASP.NET MVC 3 does not: ...

More: what does HTML5? And ASP.NET WEB APP?

Can someone explain? Thx.

Comment: i think you may have to explain why you are trying to do that requires comparison SL4, HTML5 with MVC3 as they are all very different. What is the desired outcome - is it to decide which to use in an application design?

Comment: What's your background? Do you really want an in-depth technical comparison (it does not really appear so from the question)?

Comment: You've asked 15 questions without marking any as answers.  Respect the community.

Comment: You are right...sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very extensive and can in my opinion not be answered without knowing what you want to do or a scenario could be.

Basically there's one important difference between the mentioned technologies: ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC are server side technologies while Silverlight and HTML5 applications are running on a client system.

That means that you have to decide if a server application is better because e.g. you handle lots of server data that are calculated to a simple result that is transfered to the client or if you want to use a client application that usually can have a more complex UI that the user can easily use without a need of data transfer with AJAX, postbacks etc.

Of course you have to think about security, too. The more code runs on client side, the more ways exist to attack the code. Of course there are examples of server site application that are designed very unsafe but that's another point..

I would suggest that you first of all think about the result you want to achieve and then think about the technology that suites your needs.